# SDL2 window turns red

Tags: c, sdl

When I try to draw a red pixel, the whole window is filled red:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define TITLE "SDL2 Window"
#define HEIGHT 1280
#define WIDTH 720

SDL_Window *win_init() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL initialization failed. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow(TITLE, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, HEIGHT, WIDTH, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == NULL) {
        printf("Window creation failed. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }

    return win;
}

SDL_Renderer *rend_init(SDL_Window *win) {
    SDL_Renderer *rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (rend == NULL) {
        printf("Renderer creation failed. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        exit(1);
    }

    return rend;
}

int main(void) {
    SDL_Window *win = win_init();
    SDL_Renderer *rend = rend_init(win);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 255, 0, 0, 255);

    SDL_Event event;
    int running = 1;
    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = 0;
            }
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(rend);

        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(rend, 300, 300);

        SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
        SDL_Delay(16);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

I am properly linking it with SDL2, so I see no reason why it isn't working.

Comment: From the [`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor` documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_SetRenderDrawColor#remarks): `"Set the color for drawing or filling rectangles, lines, and points, and for SDL_RenderClear()"`.  So it effectively sets the clear colour as well.